# Zebra printer code in iphone

Tags: ios, zebra-printers

Thanks for going through this. I successfully integrated Zebra Printer working in xcode and got the label printer successfully from simulator, but the problem raises the moment i tried to debug it on my device saying 
"ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/MYSystem/Desktop/MYProject/libZSDK_API.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZebraPrinterFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TcpPrinterConnection", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

What would went wrong, please help me out from this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the library for the device, not the simulator.  If you look at your install folder the `lib` folder has a `Device` and a `Simulator` directory. Link against the library in the `Device` directory.

Comment: hi..i have the same issue ..can you please explain thisss....Link against the library in the Device directory

Comment: @SteveGear, if you use the new Link-OS SDK, this shouldn't be an issue anymore...   http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the library is built for ios simulator which is using mac osx architecture which is i386 but ios device is based on ARM v6/v7 architecture that's why you are getting this error. Try to compile library for ios device.